# fill svg image not working on s7 mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fill an svg image but it's not working on samsung s7 mobile. For other devices, it works fine.

```
style="fill:white;"
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `fill="white"`? It looks like SVG styling in CSS were not supported by Samsung S7.

In general, that's more likely for SVG styles to work as plain SVG attribute than working via CSS.

Comment: i havent working via CSS to fill white.i am working on SVG styles only,still not working

Comment: By CSS I meant `style` attribute, but ok, I'm not sure that was proper word. In general, what you define in `style` attribute is exactly the same what you define in CSS files. Have you replaced whole `style="fill:white;"` formula with `fill="white"`?